# In appium app UI test, how to Locate the element in alert or Pop-ups?

Tags: java, selenium, testing, android-webview, appium

how to Locate the element in alert or Pop-ups ?
how to click the element in alert or Pop-ups ?

Comment: Can you show us your work?

Answer (score 0):

Use uiautomatorviewer to capture the IDs of the alert pop up. Mostly pop ups will have 'OK' or 'Cancel' button. Use those buttons to do a click.